# IIFE vs noraml functions, Behave differently regarding managing variables in the global scope

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

Why in Example 1 and Example 2 return different results?
A conter variable(example 1) instance still has access from the global scope.

**Example 1:**

```
const increment = (()=> {
    let counter = 0;
    //console.log(counter);
    const credits = (num) => console.log(`I have ${num} credit(s).`);
    return () => { counter++; credits(counter); }
})();

increment();//I have 1 credit(s).

increment();//I have 2 credit(s).
```

**Example 2:**

```
function a() {
    let counter = 0;
    const credits = (num) => console.log(`I have ${num} credit(s).`);
    return () => { counter++; credits(counter); }
}
a()();//I have 1 credit(s).
a()();//I have 1 credit(s).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your IIFE is only called once, but `a` is called twice and each call has its own `counter` initialized to 0.

Comment: Try this version, which only calls `a` one time: `const b = a(); b(); b();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let counter` line initializes a `counter` variable. This will occur whenever that line runs.

In the first example, you run that line *once* when you invoke the IIFE with `})()` at the end, and the function returned by the IIFE references that one `counter` variable you initialized.

In the second example, you run that line every time the `a` function runs - a new `counter` variable is created every time you do `a()`. So if you do `a()()`, you create one counter variable, increment it in the returned function, log it, *and then discard it* (since the `counter` can't be referenced by anything anymore). Calling `a()()` and then `a()()` results in two separate `counter` variables, both of which you increment by 1 and log.

If you wanted to log 2 by tweaking the second example, assign the returned function to a variable before calling it, then call that returned function twice (instead of calling `a` twice).

```js
function a() {
    let counter = 0;
    const credits = (num) => console.log(`I have ${num} credit(s).`);
    return () => { counter++; credits(counter); }
}
const fn = a();
fn();//I have 1 credit(s).
fn();//I have 2 credit(s).
```